# SVG not showing in newest version of Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg

I've got a svg icon that it's not showing in the new Chrome version. In Firefox and older versions of Chrome it works fine.

The code is this:

```
<label for="id_icon-balloon1">
     <svg class="icon" id="icon-balloon">
          <use xlink:href="#icon-balloon"></use>
     </svg>
</label>
```

And then I've got and svg included:

```
<svg width="0" height="0" class="hide">
    <symbol id="icon-balloon" viewBox="0 0 22 29">
        <title>Balloon</title>
        <path d="M11.65 25.56c.618 2.323.54 3.146 2.706 2.646l2.435-.563c2.17-.5 1.74-1.203 1.28-3.562l-6.41 1.48zm1.096-6.03c-.097.02-.195-.04-.217-.137-.03-.098.03-.196.13-.218.1-.024.19.038.22.136.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.53-1.49c-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.19.04.21.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.13m.01 2.33c-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13-.03-.1.03-.19.13-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.53-1.49c-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.03-.19-.04-.22-.13m-.31-1.35c-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.1-1.22c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.19.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.21 2.19c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.09-.02.19.04.21.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.53-1.5c-.03-.09.03-.19.13-.22.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.1-1.22c-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22M10.21 18c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.025-.1.04-.194.135-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.095-.04.194-.14.215m-.53-1.5c-.02-.097.04-.194.14-.217.1-.03.19.04.22.13.02.1-.04.196-.14.22-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14m-.3-1.353c-.02-.1.04-.197.138-.22.098-.025.197.036.22.134.02.1-.04.2-.136.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m.01 2.33c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.03.197.04.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22m-.53-1.49c-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.097-.03.195.03.217.13.02.1-.04.19-.138.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.31-1.36c-.027-.1.034-.2.132-.22.1-.03.197.04.22.13.023.1-.04.19-.14.22-.095.02-.193-.04-.215-.14m-.09-1.22c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.027-.1.035-.2.132-.22.1-.03.196.04.22.13.024.1-.04.2-.137.22m-.21 2.19c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.092-.02.192.04.213.14.03.09-.03.19-.13.22m-.52-1.49c-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.03.2.04.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.14M7.4 12.7c-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.03.093-.04.19-.13.22-.093.02-.193-.04-.22-.14m-.09-1.22c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.197.14-.22.1-.03.2.033.22.13.02.1-.04.197-.133.22m-.21 2.19c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.096.033-.194.13-.217.1-.023.2.04.22.137.025.1-.04.2-.135.22m-.52-1.48c-.026-.1.04-.19.135-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.026.1-.04.2-.135.22-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14m-.31-1.36c-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.1-.022.2.04.22.137.025.1-.04.193-.134.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14M5.95 9.5c-.02-.1.04-.196.14-.22.1-.02.196.04.22.14.03.09-.03.19-.13.21-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14m-.09-1.21c-.098.02-.196-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.137-.22.1-.02.196.04.22.14.02.093-.04.19-.136.22m-.32-1.37c-.09.022-.19-.038-.21-.137-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.096-.04.194-.14.22M6 5.733c.1-.026.2.035.22.133.03.1-.04.195-.13.22-.09.02-.19-.04-.21-.14-.02-.1.04-.195.14-.22m.21-2.19c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.196-.14.22-.09.02-.19-.04-.21-.14-.02-.096.04-.194.137-.22m.53 1.495c.027.1-.04.2-.133.22-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14-.022-.09.04-.19.137-.21.1-.02.2.04.22.14m-.02-2.32c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.03.1-.04.2-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22m.53 1.49c.03.1-.03.2-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.13-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14m-.02-2.35c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.03-.19-.04-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m.32 1.35c.1-.03.2.03.22.13.02.09-.04.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m.21-2.19c.1-.03.2.04.22.13.03.1-.04.2-.13.22-.09.03-.19-.04-.21-.13-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22m.53 1.5c.02.1-.04.2-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.1-.02.2.04.22.14m.31 1.36c.03.1-.03.2-.13.22-.09.03-.19-.04-.21-.13-.03-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14m-.01-2.33c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.03.1-.04.19-.13.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22M9 2.95c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.09-.033.19-.13.21-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22m.52 1.5c.03.1-.04.2-.13.22-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.022.19.04.21.138m.31 1.36c.02.094-.04.19-.14.214-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14-.02-.096.04-.195.14-.217.1-.02.19.04.22.14m.31 1.354c.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.21-.14-.024-.1.04-.19.136-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14m.31 1.36c.028.1-.033.2-.13.22-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.13-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.03.2.04.22.13m.31 1.35c.03.1-.036.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.094-.03.19.04.214.13m.32 1.35c.02.1-.04.192-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.092-.02.19.04.22.133m-.127 3.41c.1-.02.195.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.13-.022-.1.04-.198.138-.22m-.31-1.35c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m-.45-1.14c-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.21-.14m-.07 1.97c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.092-.04.19-.133.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.025-.1.04-.2.14-.22m-.33-1.37c.1-.02.195.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.137.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.138-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22m-.45-1.14c-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.03.1-.03.2-.13.22-.1.03-.19-.04-.22-.13m-.07 1.97c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.03.1-.04.2-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22M9 12.24c.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.193-.14.22-.093.02-.19-.04-.213-.14-.03-.1.03-.2.13-.22m-.32-1.35c.1-.027.195.04.22.133.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.193-.04-.22-.133-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22M8.2 9.75c-.02-.1.04-.194.14-.22.1-.02.197.04.22.14.02.095-.04.193-.14.22-.1.02-.193-.04-.22-.14m-.07 1.97c.1-.03.195.04.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.138.22-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.137-.22m-.32-1.37c.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.192-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.197.13-.22m-.36-1.38c.09-.022.19.04.22.138.02.098-.04.196-.14.22-.1.022-.2-.04-.22-.138-.02-.1.04-.197.14-.22m-.02-3.19c-.1.023-.2-.038-.22-.136-.03-.1.03-.197.13-.22.1-.023.19.04.22.137.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.44 1.14c.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.19.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14m.07-1.97c-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.25 3.32c.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.09.04-.19.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14m.07-1.97c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.45 1.14c.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.03-.19.13-.22.09-.02.19.04.21.14m.07-1.97c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.32 1.35c-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13-.03-.1.04-.19.14-.22.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.21 2.19c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.09.04-.19.13-.21.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.23 1c.09-.02.19.04.21.14.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.29-1.83c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.193.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.54 2.35c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.023.1-.04.2-.138.22-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.19.135-.22m-.23-1c-.097.03-.19-.04-.217-.13-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.09-.02.19.04.21.14.03.1-.04.2-.13.22M7 7.83c-.022-.1.04-.2.137-.22.098-.026.196.04.218.134.024.1-.038.19-.135.22-.1.02-.197-.04-.22-.14m-.07 1.97c.095-.02.194.04.218.13.022.1-.04.19-.138.22-.098.02-.197-.04-.217-.14-.026-.1.036-.2.136-.22m-.25-3.32c-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.31.97c-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.13-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.23 1c.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.197-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.193.13-.22m4.7 4.098c.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.03.19.03.22.13m.31 1.36c.02.09-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.03.2.03.22.13m.31 1.36c.02.09-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.028.19.033.21.13m.32 1.36c.03.1-.04.2-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.19.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.21.14M10 20.17c-.1.02-.194-.04-.22-.137-.02-.1.04-.193.14-.22.1-.02.198.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.135.22m-.84-.52c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.135-.02-.1.04-.197.14-.22.1-.02.195.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.834-.52c-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.14-.02-.097.04-.195.14-.218.1-.03.2.032.22.13.02.1-.04.196-.14.22m-.83-.53c-.1.022-.19-.04-.22-.136-.02-.1.04-.196.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.196-.14.22M7 17.1c-.023-.096.037-.195.136-.217.1-.023.196.038.22.135.022.1-.04.198-.138.22-.098.022-.197-.038-.22-.137m-.3.98c-.1.02-.197-.04-.22-.13-.022-.1.04-.19.136-.22.098-.02.196.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.137.22m-.533-1.49c-.02-.09.04-.19.138-.21.098-.02.195.04.218.14.023.1-.038.2-.136.22-.1.02-.197-.04-.22-.14m-.312-1.35c-.023-.1.04-.19.137-.22.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.13m.01 2.32c-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.53-1.49c-.03-.09.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.19.04.21.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.13M5 14.73c-.02-.1.04-.2.136-.22.1-.02.197.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.138.22-.1.02-.197-.04-.22-.14m.01 2.322c-.098.02-.196-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.137-.22.1-.02.197.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.136.21m-.53-1.5c-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.024.19.04.21.136.03.09-.04.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.31-1.35c-.03-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.13.02.1-.03.2-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m.01 2.32c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.02.19.04.21.13.02.1-.04.2-.14.22M3.64 15c-.02-.093.04-.19.14-.213.1-.025.19.037.22.135.02.1-.04.195-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.31-1.355c-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.198-.14.22-.1.025-.2-.04-.22-.134m-.097-1.22c-.093.024-.19-.04-.213-.136-.025-.095.036-.193.135-.215.096-.023.196.037.22.135.02.1-.04.196-.14.22m-.206 2.19c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.194.13-.22.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.05.2-.14.22m-.52-1.48c-.02-.094.04-.192.13-.215.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.097-.04.196-.14.22-.1.022-.2-.04-.22-.138M2.4 11.94c-.1.023-.193-.04-.22-.137-.02-.1.04-.198.14-.22.1-.02.197.04.22.137.02.1-.04.2-.135.22m-.21 2.19c-.095.02-.193-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.197.04.22.14.024.1-.04.2-.136.22m-.53-1.49c-.03-.1.04-.19.13-.22.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13m-.31-1.35c-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.09-.025.19.04.22.133.02.1-.04.193-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.1-1.22c-.1.025-.19-.036-.22-.135-.02-.1.04-.196.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.096-.04.195-.14.22m-.21 2.185c-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.134.03.1-.04.2-.13.22m-.53-1.49c-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.027.2.034.22.132.03.1-.03.2-.13.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.21-.14m.34-2.4c.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.52-.84c.1-.03.2.04.22.13.03.1-.03.2-.13.22-.09.02-.19-.04-.21-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.31 1.35c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.03.1-.03.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.21-2.19c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.32 3.68c.03.1-.03.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.02.19.04.21.14m-.01-2.33c.09-.03.19.03.22.13.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m.2-2.19c.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.14-.22m.31 1.35c.1-.03.2.04.22.13.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.2-2.2c.1-.03.2.03.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m.52 1.49c.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.026-.1.04-.2.133-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.13m0-2.32c.1-.02.2.04.22.132.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.09.03-.19-.03-.21-.13-.03-.1.04-.19.13-.22M4 5.642c.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.09.02-.19-.04-.21-.13-.03-.1.03-.19.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14M4 3.33c.096-.02.194.04.217.14.022.1-.04.2-.136.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.133-.02-.1.04-.196.14-.22m.53 1.494c.03.1-.03.2-.13.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14M4.53 2.5c.1-.024.2.04.22.136.03.098-.04.196-.13.22-.09.022-.19-.04-.22-.138-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22M4.2 7.23c-.1.025-.2-.036-.22-.135-.023-.098.04-.196.136-.218.1-.024.198.038.22.136.022.098-.04.196-.137.22m-.19 5.377c.09-.022.19.038.21.137.02.098-.04.196-.14.22-.09.022-.19-.04-.21-.138-.03-.1.03-.2.13-.22m-.31-1.36c.1-.03.2.03.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.21-2.19c.09-.03.19.04.22.13.02.09-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22m-.23-1c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.02.19.04.21.14.02.09-.04.19-.14.21m-.29 1.84c.09-.03.19.03.21.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m-.45-1.14c-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.03.2.04.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.3.97c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.14.22m.23 1c.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.09-.04.19-.14.21-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m1.57-.18c.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.03.19.04.22.13m.09 1.22c.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22M5 13.19c.023.1-.04.2-.137.22-.1.02-.198-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.13m.614.386c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22M12.38.01c5.825 3.736 7.257 11.643 3.944 19.74l-.93.213C19.1 11.43 17.304 3.35 11 .1c-.458.053-.926.13-1.403.226l4.598 19.915-.753.17L8.846.5c-.472.118-.928.256-1.363.408-.805 1.082-1.386 2.25-1.754 3.474.07.005.14.048.16.127.02.09-.04.19-.14.21-.04.01-.08-.01-.11-.02-.35 1.3-.46 2.66-.33 4.05.07.01.13.05.15.13.02.09-.04.18-.13.21.04.34.1.69.17 1.04.02-.01.03-.03.05-.04.09-.03.19.04.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.03 0-.05-.01-.08-.02.08.34.17.68.28 1.03.01-.01.01-.02.02-.02.09-.02.19.04.21.13.02.1-.04.2-.14.22h-.01c.11.35.25.7.39 1.05.02.02.05.05.06.09 0 .01-.01.03-.01.05.24.58.53 1.17.85 1.74.02-.03.05-.05.08-.06.1-.03.2.03.22.13.02.09-.04.18-.13.21.31.52.65 1.04 1.02 1.55.01 0 .02-.02.03-.02.1-.02.2.04.22.13.02.06-.01.12-.06.16.54.72 1.15 1.42 1.81 2.11.01-.01.01-.02.02-.02.1-.02.19.04.22.14.01.04-.01.07-.02.11.16.16.33.33.5.49-.03-.1.03-.19.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.03.01-.06-.01-.09-.02.3.28.61.57.93.85l-.93.21c-.12-.1-.22-.2-.33-.31-.03.05-.06.08-.12.09-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13-.01-.08.03-.15.09-.19-.95-.9-1.81-1.84-2.55-2.81.02.1-.04.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.04-.01.09 0 .12.02-.4-.53-.76-1.07-1.09-1.61-.03.03-.06.06-.1.07-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22h.01c-.57-.95-1.04-1.91-1.4-2.88-.1.01-.19-.04-.21-.14-.02-.08.02-.15.09-.19-.13-.36-.24-.72-.34-1.08-.03-.027-.06-.055-.07-.09-.01-.04 0-.07.02-.107-.1-.38-.19-.76-.26-1.14-.04-.02-.07-.06-.08-.11-.01-.053.01-.11.05-.15-.06-.355-.11-.71-.13-1.07l-.01.01c-.1.022-.2-.04-.22-.138-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.03-.01.05 0 .08.01-.03-.64-.02-1.28.05-1.908-.03-.02-.05-.04-.06-.08-.02-.078.02-.14.08-.18.08-.655.23-1.297.42-1.93-.02.02-.04.05-.08.055-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.025-.1.035-.195.134-.22.09-.02.174.04.203.12.07-.22.15-.434.233-.65-.02-.02-.05-.05-.06-.08-.02-.1.04-.196.14-.22.02-.003.03.007.04.007.23-.55.49-1.08.8-1.6C4.81 2 3.69 2.79 2.8 3.694c.006.01.02.02.02.03.02.1-.04.2-.135.22-.04.01-.083 0-.12-.02-.15.17-.3.34-.435.51.08 0 .15.05.17.13.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.09.02-.17-.03-.21-.12-.15.2-.29.41-.42.62.01 0 .013-.02.025-.02.1-.02.2.04.22.14.023.1-.04.2-.137.22-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.14v-.03c-.13.22-.248.436-.35.658.08 0 .16.04.18.13.02.095-.04.193-.14.22-.07.01-.128-.02-.17-.067-.09.21-.17.43-.24.64.003.01.02.02.02.03.02.08-.03.16-.104.2C.46 7.89.35 8.51.33 9.14c.09-.01.18.04.2.13.02.093-.04.19-.14.214-.02.005-.04-.008-.065-.01.004 1.23.305 2.487.923 3.72.098-.02.195.04.218.14.02.064-.01.12-.06.163.29.532.65 1.06 1.06 1.58.07.015.13.054.14.127.01.01 0 .03 0 .04.158.187.32.37.49.553-.022-.094.04-.192.136-.214.1-.02.2.04.22.133.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.04.01-.076-.004-.108-.02 1.166 1.226 2.7 2.37 4.63 3.374 1.233.64 2.555 1.567 2.79 2.594L11 23.36l6.677-1.54-.33-1.436c-.235-1.027.546-2.44 1.376-3.556 6.74-9.073 2.195-17-6.345-16.83"/>
    </symbol>
    (...) //other icons
</svg>
```

Do you have any idea what could be causing this?

Thank you :)

Comment: How can create SVG code?

Comment: @TusharKumawat English is not my native language. Sorry if I didn't use the correct term. I've got that piece in a template as is html and in the new version of Chrome is not showing.

Comment: Do you have SVG image?

Comment: @TusharKumawat It's not an image. The svg icon is defined in the second block of code of my question. the "symbol" parte is the definition of the icon.

Comment: Okay, Please open icon in the chrome browser if look fine then you can use the source code.

Comment: @TusharKumawat The icon doesn't open in the chrome browser (in the newest version). Here's a fiddle, if you run it on chrome you can't see the icon and if you run it on Firefox or older version of chrome you can see the icon.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/96n8z4cw/

Comment: When did you open in chrome it's look fine?

Comment: Your second SVG element has the same id as the symbol. Fix that

Comment: Please look answer hopefully for you helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've told you in my comment your second SVG element has the same id as the symbol. Fix that

```html
<label for="id_icon-balloon1">
     <svg class="icon" id="icon-balloon_whatever" viewBox="0 0 22 29" width="44">
          <use xlink:href="#icon-balloon"></use>
     </svg>
</label>


<svg width="0" height="0" class="hide">
    <symbol id="icon-balloon" viewBox="0 0 22 29">
        <title>Balloon</title>
        <path d="M11.65 25.56c.618 2.323.54 3.146 2.706 2.646l2.435-.563c2.17-.5 1.74-1.203 1.28-3.562l-6.41 1.48zm1.096-6.03c-.097.02-.195-.04-.217-.137-.03-.098.03-.196.13-.218.1-.024.19.038.22.136.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.53-1.49c-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.19.04.21.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.13m.01 2.33c-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13-.03-.1.03-.19.13-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.53-1.49c-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.03-.19-.04-.22-.13m-.31-1.35c-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.1-1.22c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.19.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.21 2.19c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.09-.02.19.04.21.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.53-1.5c-.03-.09.03-.19.13-.22.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.1-1.22c-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22M10.21 18c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.025-.1.04-.194.135-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.095-.04.194-.14.215m-.53-1.5c-.02-.097.04-.194.14-.217.1-.03.19.04.22.13.02.1-.04.196-.14.22-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14m-.3-1.353c-.02-.1.04-.197.138-.22.098-.025.197.036.22.134.02.1-.04.2-.136.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m.01 2.33c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.03.197.04.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22m-.53-1.49c-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.097-.03.195.03.217.13.02.1-.04.19-.138.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.31-1.36c-.027-.1.034-.2.132-.22.1-.03.197.04.22.13.023.1-.04.19-.14.22-.095.02-.193-.04-.215-.14m-.09-1.22c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.027-.1.035-.2.132-.22.1-.03.196.04.22.13.024.1-.04.2-.137.22m-.21 2.19c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.092-.02.192.04.213.14.03.09-.03.19-.13.22m-.52-1.49c-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.03.2.04.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.14M7.4 12.7c-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.03.093-.04.19-.13.22-.093.02-.193-.04-.22-.14m-.09-1.22c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.197.14-.22.1-.03.2.033.22.13.02.1-.04.197-.133.22m-.21 2.19c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.096.033-.194.13-.217.1-.023.2.04.22.137.025.1-.04.2-.135.22m-.52-1.48c-.026-.1.04-.19.135-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.026.1-.04.2-.135.22-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14m-.31-1.36c-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.1-.022.2.04.22.137.025.1-.04.193-.134.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14M5.95 9.5c-.02-.1.04-.196.14-.22.1-.02.196.04.22.14.03.09-.03.19-.13.21-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14m-.09-1.21c-.098.02-.196-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.137-.22.1-.02.196.04.22.14.02.093-.04.19-.136.22m-.32-1.37c-.09.022-.19-.038-.21-.137-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.096-.04.194-.14.22M6 5.733c.1-.026.2.035.22.133.03.1-.04.195-.13.22-.09.02-.19-.04-.21-.14-.02-.1.04-.195.14-.22m.21-2.19c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.196-.14.22-.09.02-.19-.04-.21-.14-.02-.096.04-.194.137-.22m.53 1.495c.027.1-.04.2-.133.22-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14-.022-.09.04-.19.137-.21.1-.02.2.04.22.14m-.02-2.32c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.03.1-.04.2-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22m.53 1.49c.03.1-.03.2-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.13-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14m-.02-2.35c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.03-.19-.04-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m.32 1.35c.1-.03.2.03.22.13.02.09-.04.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m.21-2.19c.1-.03.2.04.22.13.03.1-.04.2-.13.22-.09.03-.19-.04-.21-.13-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22m.53 1.5c.02.1-.04.2-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.1-.02.2.04.22.14m.31 1.36c.03.1-.03.2-.13.22-.09.03-.19-.04-.21-.13-.03-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14m-.01-2.33c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.03.1-.04.19-.13.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22M9 2.95c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.09-.033.19-.13.21-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22m.52 1.5c.03.1-.04.2-.13.22-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.022.19.04.21.138m.31 1.36c.02.094-.04.19-.14.214-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14-.02-.096.04-.195.14-.217.1-.02.19.04.22.14m.31 1.354c.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.21-.14-.024-.1.04-.19.136-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14m.31 1.36c.028.1-.033.2-.13.22-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.13-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.03.2.04.22.13m.31 1.35c.03.1-.036.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.094-.03.19.04.214.13m.32 1.35c.02.1-.04.192-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.092-.02.19.04.22.133m-.127 3.41c.1-.02.195.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.13-.022-.1.04-.198.138-.22m-.31-1.35c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m-.45-1.14c-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.21-.14m-.07 1.97c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.092-.04.19-.133.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.025-.1.04-.2.14-.22m-.33-1.37c.1-.02.195.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.137.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.138-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22m-.45-1.14c-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.03.1-.03.2-.13.22-.1.03-.19-.04-.22-.13m-.07 1.97c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.03.1-.04.2-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22M9 12.24c.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.193-.14.22-.093.02-.19-.04-.213-.14-.03-.1.03-.2.13-.22m-.32-1.35c.1-.027.195.04.22.133.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.193-.04-.22-.133-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22M8.2 9.75c-.02-.1.04-.194.14-.22.1-.02.197.04.22.14.02.095-.04.193-.14.22-.1.02-.193-.04-.22-.14m-.07 1.97c.1-.03.195.04.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.138.22-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.137-.22m-.32-1.37c.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.192-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.197.13-.22m-.36-1.38c.09-.022.19.04.22.138.02.098-.04.196-.14.22-.1.022-.2-.04-.22-.138-.02-.1.04-.197.14-.22m-.02-3.19c-.1.023-.2-.038-.22-.136-.03-.1.03-.197.13-.22.1-.023.19.04.22.137.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.44 1.14c.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.19.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14m.07-1.97c-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.25 3.32c.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.09.04-.19.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14m.07-1.97c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.45 1.14c.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.03-.19.13-.22.09-.02.19.04.21.14m.07-1.97c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.32 1.35c-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13-.03-.1.04-.19.14-.22.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.21 2.19c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.09.04-.19.13-.21.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.23 1c.09-.02.19.04.21.14.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.29-1.83c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.193.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.54 2.35c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.023.1-.04.2-.138.22-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.19.135-.22m-.23-1c-.097.03-.19-.04-.217-.13-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.09-.02.19.04.21.14.03.1-.04.2-.13.22M7 7.83c-.022-.1.04-.2.137-.22.098-.026.196.04.218.134.024.1-.038.19-.135.22-.1.02-.197-.04-.22-.14m-.07 1.97c.095-.02.194.04.218.13.022.1-.04.19-.138.22-.098.02-.197-.04-.217-.14-.026-.1.036-.2.136-.22m-.25-3.32c-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.31.97c-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.13-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.23 1c.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.197-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.193.13-.22m4.7 4.098c.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.03.19.03.22.13m.31 1.36c.02.09-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.03.2.03.22.13m.31 1.36c.02.09-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.028.19.033.21.13m.32 1.36c.03.1-.04.2-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.19.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.21.14M10 20.17c-.1.02-.194-.04-.22-.137-.02-.1.04-.193.14-.22.1-.02.198.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.135.22m-.84-.52c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.135-.02-.1.04-.197.14-.22.1-.02.195.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.834-.52c-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.14-.02-.097.04-.195.14-.218.1-.03.2.032.22.13.02.1-.04.196-.14.22m-.83-.53c-.1.022-.19-.04-.22-.136-.02-.1.04-.196.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.196-.14.22M7 17.1c-.023-.096.037-.195.136-.217.1-.023.196.038.22.135.022.1-.04.198-.138.22-.098.022-.197-.038-.22-.137m-.3.98c-.1.02-.197-.04-.22-.13-.022-.1.04-.19.136-.22.098-.02.196.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.137.22m-.533-1.49c-.02-.09.04-.19.138-.21.098-.02.195.04.218.14.023.1-.038.2-.136.22-.1.02-.197-.04-.22-.14m-.312-1.35c-.023-.1.04-.19.137-.22.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.13m.01 2.32c-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.53-1.49c-.03-.09.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.19.04.21.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.13M5 14.73c-.02-.1.04-.2.136-.22.1-.02.197.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.138.22-.1.02-.197-.04-.22-.14m.01 2.322c-.098.02-.196-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.137-.22.1-.02.197.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.136.21m-.53-1.5c-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.024.19.04.21.136.03.09-.04.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.31-1.35c-.03-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.13.02.1-.03.2-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m.01 2.32c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.02.19.04.21.13.02.1-.04.2-.14.22M3.64 15c-.02-.093.04-.19.14-.213.1-.025.19.037.22.135.02.1-.04.195-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.31-1.355c-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.198-.14.22-.1.025-.2-.04-.22-.134m-.097-1.22c-.093.024-.19-.04-.213-.136-.025-.095.036-.193.135-.215.096-.023.196.037.22.135.02.1-.04.196-.14.22m-.206 2.19c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.194.13-.22.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.05.2-.14.22m-.52-1.48c-.02-.094.04-.192.13-.215.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.097-.04.196-.14.22-.1.022-.2-.04-.22-.138M2.4 11.94c-.1.023-.193-.04-.22-.137-.02-.1.04-.198.14-.22.1-.02.197.04.22.137.02.1-.04.2-.135.22m-.21 2.19c-.095.02-.193-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.197.04.22.14.024.1-.04.2-.136.22m-.53-1.49c-.03-.1.04-.19.13-.22.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13m-.31-1.35c-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.09-.025.19.04.22.133.02.1-.04.193-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.1-1.22c-.1.025-.19-.036-.22-.135-.02-.1.04-.196.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.096-.04.195-.14.22m-.21 2.185c-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.134.03.1-.04.2-.13.22m-.53-1.49c-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.027.2.034.22.132.03.1-.03.2-.13.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.21-.14m.34-2.4c.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.52-.84c.1-.03.2.04.22.13.03.1-.03.2-.13.22-.09.02-.19-.04-.21-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.31 1.35c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.03.1-.03.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.21-2.19c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.32 3.68c.03.1-.03.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.02.19.04.21.14m-.01-2.33c.09-.03.19.03.22.13.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m.2-2.19c.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.14-.22m.31 1.35c.1-.03.2.04.22.13.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.2-2.2c.1-.03.2.03.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m.52 1.49c.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.026-.1.04-.2.133-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.13m0-2.32c.1-.02.2.04.22.132.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.09.03-.19-.03-.21-.13-.03-.1.04-.19.13-.22M4 5.642c.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.09.02-.19-.04-.21-.13-.03-.1.03-.19.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14M4 3.33c.096-.02.194.04.217.14.022.1-.04.2-.136.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.133-.02-.1.04-.196.14-.22m.53 1.494c.03.1-.03.2-.13.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14M4.53 2.5c.1-.024.2.04.22.136.03.098-.04.196-.13.22-.09.022-.19-.04-.22-.138-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22M4.2 7.23c-.1.025-.2-.036-.22-.135-.023-.098.04-.196.136-.218.1-.024.198.038.22.136.022.098-.04.196-.137.22m-.19 5.377c.09-.022.19.038.21.137.02.098-.04.196-.14.22-.09.022-.19-.04-.21-.138-.03-.1.03-.2.13-.22m-.31-1.36c.1-.03.2.03.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.21-2.19c.09-.03.19.04.22.13.02.09-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22m-.23-1c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.02.19.04.21.14.02.09-.04.19-.14.21m-.29 1.84c.09-.03.19.03.21.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m-.45-1.14c-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.03.2.04.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.3.97c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.14.22m.23 1c.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.09-.04.19-.14.21-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m1.57-.18c.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.03.19.04.22.13m.09 1.22c.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22M5 13.19c.023.1-.04.2-.137.22-.1.02-.198-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.13m.614.386c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22M12.38.01c5.825 3.736 7.257 11.643 3.944 19.74l-.93.213C19.1 11.43 17.304 3.35 11 .1c-.458.053-.926.13-1.403.226l4.598 19.915-.753.17L8.846.5c-.472.118-.928.256-1.363.408-.805 1.082-1.386 2.25-1.754 3.474.07.005.14.048.16.127.02.09-.04.19-.14.21-.04.01-.08-.01-.11-.02-.35 1.3-.46 2.66-.33 4.05.07.01.13.05.15.13.02.09-.04.18-.13.21.04.34.1.69.17 1.04.02-.01.03-.03.05-.04.09-.03.19.04.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.03 0-.05-.01-.08-.02.08.34.17.68.28 1.03.01-.01.01-.02.02-.02.09-.02.19.04.21.13.02.1-.04.2-.14.22h-.01c.11.35.25.7.39 1.05.02.02.05.05.06.09 0 .01-.01.03-.01.05.24.58.53 1.17.85 1.74.02-.03.05-.05.08-.06.1-.03.2.03.22.13.02.09-.04.18-.13.21.31.52.65 1.04 1.02 1.55.01 0 .02-.02.03-.02.1-.02.2.04.22.13.02.06-.01.12-.06.16.54.72 1.15 1.42 1.81 2.11.01-.01.01-.02.02-.02.1-.02.19.04.22.14.01.04-.01.07-.02.11.16.16.33.33.5.49-.03-.1.03-.19.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.03.01-.06-.01-.09-.02.3.28.61.57.93.85l-.93.21c-.12-.1-.22-.2-.33-.31-.03.05-.06.08-.12.09-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13-.01-.08.03-.15.09-.19-.95-.9-1.81-1.84-2.55-2.81.02.1-.04.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.04-.01.09 0 .12.02-.4-.53-.76-1.07-1.09-1.61-.03.03-.06.06-.1.07-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22h.01c-.57-.95-1.04-1.91-1.4-2.88-.1.01-.19-.04-.21-.14-.02-.08.02-.15.09-.19-.13-.36-.24-.72-.34-1.08-.03-.027-.06-.055-.07-.09-.01-.04 0-.07.02-.107-.1-.38-.19-.76-.26-1.14-.04-.02-.07-.06-.08-.11-.01-.053.01-.11.05-.15-.06-.355-.11-.71-.13-1.07l-.01.01c-.1.022-.2-.04-.22-.138-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.03-.01.05 0 .08.01-.03-.64-.02-1.28.05-1.908-.03-.02-.05-.04-.06-.08-.02-.078.02-.14.08-.18.08-.655.23-1.297.42-1.93-.02.02-.04.05-.08.055-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.025-.1.035-.195.134-.22.09-.02.174.04.203.12.07-.22.15-.434.233-.65-.02-.02-.05-.05-.06-.08-.02-.1.04-.196.14-.22.02-.003.03.007.04.007.23-.55.49-1.08.8-1.6C4.81 2 3.69 2.79 2.8 3.694c.006.01.02.02.02.03.02.1-.04.2-.135.22-.04.01-.083 0-.12-.02-.15.17-.3.34-.435.51.08 0 .15.05.17.13.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.09.02-.17-.03-.21-.12-.15.2-.29.41-.42.62.01 0 .013-.02.025-.02.1-.02.2.04.22.14.023.1-.04.2-.137.22-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.14v-.03c-.13.22-.248.436-.35.658.08 0 .16.04.18.13.02.095-.04.193-.14.22-.07.01-.128-.02-.17-.067-.09.21-.17.43-.24.64.003.01.02.02.02.03.02.08-.03.16-.104.2C.46 7.89.35 8.51.33 9.14c.09-.01.18.04.2.13.02.093-.04.19-.14.214-.02.005-.04-.008-.065-.01.004 1.23.305 2.487.923 3.72.098-.02.195.04.218.14.02.064-.01.12-.06.163.29.532.65 1.06 1.06 1.58.07.015.13.054.14.127.01.01 0 .03 0 .04.158.187.32.37.49.553-.022-.094.04-.192.136-.214.1-.02.2.04.22.133.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.04.01-.076-.004-.108-.02 1.166 1.226 2.7 2.37 4.63 3.374 1.233.64 2.555 1.567 2.79 2.594L11 23.36l6.677-1.54-.33-1.436c-.235-1.027.546-2.44 1.376-3.556 6.74-9.073 2.195-17-6.345-16.83"/>
    </symbol>
    (...) //other icons
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use code

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">

        <path d="M11.65 25.56c.618 2.323.54 3.146 2.706 2.646l2.435-.563c2.17-.5 1.74-1.203 1.28-3.562l-6.41 1.48zm1.096-6.03c-.097.02-.195-.04-.217-.137-.03-.098.03-.196.13-.218.1-.024.19.038.22.136.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.53-1.49c-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.19.04.21.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.13m.01 2.33c-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13-.03-.1.03-.19.13-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.53-1.49c-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.03-.19-.04-.22-.13m-.31-1.35c-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.1-1.22c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.19.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.21 2.19c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.09-.02.19.04.21.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.53-1.5c-.03-.09.03-.19.13-.22.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.1-1.22c-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22M10.21 18c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.025-.1.04-.194.135-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.095-.04.194-.14.215m-.53-1.5c-.02-.097.04-.194.14-.217.1-.03.19.04.22.13.02.1-.04.196-.14.22-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14m-.3-1.353c-.02-.1.04-.197.138-.22.098-.025.197.036.22.134.02.1-.04.2-.136.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m.01 2.33c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.03.197.04.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22m-.53-1.49c-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.097-.03.195.03.217.13.02.1-.04.19-.138.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.31-1.36c-.027-.1.034-.2.132-.22.1-.03.197.04.22.13.023.1-.04.19-.14.22-.095.02-.193-.04-.215-.14m-.09-1.22c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.027-.1.035-.2.132-.22.1-.03.196.04.22.13.024.1-.04.2-.137.22m-.21 2.19c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.092-.02.192.04.213.14.03.09-.03.19-.13.22m-.52-1.49c-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.03.2.04.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.14M7.4 12.7c-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.03.093-.04.19-.13.22-.093.02-.193-.04-.22-.14m-.09-1.22c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.197.14-.22.1-.03.2.033.22.13.02.1-.04.197-.133.22m-.21 2.19c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.096.033-.194.13-.217.1-.023.2.04.22.137.025.1-.04.2-.135.22m-.52-1.48c-.026-.1.04-.19.135-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.026.1-.04.2-.135.22-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14m-.31-1.36c-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.1-.022.2.04.22.137.025.1-.04.193-.134.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14M5.95 9.5c-.02-.1.04-.196.14-.22.1-.02.196.04.22.14.03.09-.03.19-.13.21-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14m-.09-1.21c-.098.02-.196-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.137-.22.1-.02.196.04.22.14.02.093-.04.19-.136.22m-.32-1.37c-.09.022-.19-.038-.21-.137-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.096-.04.194-.14.22M6 5.733c.1-.026.2.035.22.133.03.1-.04.195-.13.22-.09.02-.19-.04-.21-.14-.02-.1.04-.195.14-.22m.21-2.19c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.196-.14.22-.09.02-.19-.04-.21-.14-.02-.096.04-.194.137-.22m.53 1.495c.027.1-.04.2-.133.22-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14-.022-.09.04-.19.137-.21.1-.02.2.04.22.14m-.02-2.32c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.03.1-.04.2-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22m.53 1.49c.03.1-.03.2-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.13-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14m-.02-2.35c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.03-.19-.04-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m.32 1.35c.1-.03.2.03.22.13.02.09-.04.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m.21-2.19c.1-.03.2.04.22.13.03.1-.04.2-.13.22-.09.03-.19-.04-.21-.13-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22m.53 1.5c.02.1-.04.2-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.1-.02.2.04.22.14m.31 1.36c.03.1-.03.2-.13.22-.09.03-.19-.04-.21-.13-.03-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14m-.01-2.33c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.03.1-.04.19-.13.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22M9 2.95c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.09-.033.19-.13.21-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22m.52 1.5c.03.1-.04.2-.13.22-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.022.19.04.21.138m.31 1.36c.02.094-.04.19-.14.214-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14-.02-.096.04-.195.14-.217.1-.02.19.04.22.14m.31 1.354c.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.21-.14-.024-.1.04-.19.136-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14m.31 1.36c.028.1-.033.2-.13.22-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.13-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.03.2.04.22.13m.31 1.35c.03.1-.036.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.094-.03.19.04.214.13m.32 1.35c.02.1-.04.192-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.092-.02.19.04.22.133m-.127 3.41c.1-.02.195.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.13-.022-.1.04-.198.138-.22m-.31-1.35c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m-.45-1.14c-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.21-.14m-.07 1.97c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.092-.04.19-.133.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.025-.1.04-.2.14-.22m-.33-1.37c.1-.02.195.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.137.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.138-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22m-.45-1.14c-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.03.1-.03.2-.13.22-.1.03-.19-.04-.22-.13m-.07 1.97c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.03.1-.04.2-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22M9 12.24c.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.193-.14.22-.093.02-.19-.04-.213-.14-.03-.1.03-.2.13-.22m-.32-1.35c.1-.027.195.04.22.133.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.193-.04-.22-.133-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22M8.2 9.75c-.02-.1.04-.194.14-.22.1-.02.197.04.22.14.02.095-.04.193-.14.22-.1.02-.193-.04-.22-.14m-.07 1.97c.1-.03.195.04.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.138.22-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.137-.22m-.32-1.37c.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.192-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.197.13-.22m-.36-1.38c.09-.022.19.04.22.138.02.098-.04.196-.14.22-.1.022-.2-.04-.22-.138-.02-.1.04-.197.14-.22m-.02-3.19c-.1.023-.2-.038-.22-.136-.03-.1.03-.197.13-.22.1-.023.19.04.22.137.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.44 1.14c.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.19.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14m.07-1.97c-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.25 3.32c.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.09.04-.19.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14m.07-1.97c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.45 1.14c.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.03-.19.13-.22.09-.02.19.04.21.14m.07-1.97c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.32 1.35c-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13-.03-.1.04-.19.14-.22.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.21 2.19c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.09.04-.19.13-.21.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.23 1c.09-.02.19.04.21.14.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.29-1.83c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.193.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.54 2.35c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.023.1-.04.2-.138.22-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.19.135-.22m-.23-1c-.097.03-.19-.04-.217-.13-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.09-.02.19.04.21.14.03.1-.04.2-.13.22M7 7.83c-.022-.1.04-.2.137-.22.098-.026.196.04.218.134.024.1-.038.19-.135.22-.1.02-.197-.04-.22-.14m-.07 1.97c.095-.02.194.04.218.13.022.1-.04.19-.138.22-.098.02-.197-.04-.217-.14-.026-.1.036-.2.136-.22m-.25-3.32c-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.31.97c-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.13-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.23 1c.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.197-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.193.13-.22m4.7 4.098c.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.03.19.03.22.13m.31 1.36c.02.09-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.03.2.03.22.13m.31 1.36c.02.09-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.028.19.033.21.13m.32 1.36c.03.1-.04.2-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.19.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.21.14M10 20.17c-.1.02-.194-.04-.22-.137-.02-.1.04-.193.14-.22.1-.02.198.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.135.22m-.84-.52c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.135-.02-.1.04-.197.14-.22.1-.02.195.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.834-.52c-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.14-.02-.097.04-.195.14-.218.1-.03.2.032.22.13.02.1-.04.196-.14.22m-.83-.53c-.1.022-.19-.04-.22-.136-.02-.1.04-.196.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.196-.14.22M7 17.1c-.023-.096.037-.195.136-.217.1-.023.196.038.22.135.022.1-.04.198-.138.22-.098.022-.197-.038-.22-.137m-.3.98c-.1.02-.197-.04-.22-.13-.022-.1.04-.19.136-.22.098-.02.196.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.137.22m-.533-1.49c-.02-.09.04-.19.138-.21.098-.02.195.04.218.14.023.1-.038.2-.136.22-.1.02-.197-.04-.22-.14m-.312-1.35c-.023-.1.04-.19.137-.22.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.13m.01 2.32c-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.53-1.49c-.03-.09.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.19.04.21.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.13M5 14.73c-.02-.1.04-.2.136-.22.1-.02.197.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.138.22-.1.02-.197-.04-.22-.14m.01 2.322c-.098.02-.196-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.137-.22.1-.02.197.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.136.21m-.53-1.5c-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.024.19.04.21.136.03.09-.04.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.31-1.35c-.03-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.13.02.1-.03.2-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m.01 2.32c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.02.19.04.21.13.02.1-.04.2-.14.22M3.64 15c-.02-.093.04-.19.14-.213.1-.025.19.037.22.135.02.1-.04.195-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.31-1.355c-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.198-.14.22-.1.025-.2-.04-.22-.134m-.097-1.22c-.093.024-.19-.04-.213-.136-.025-.095.036-.193.135-.215.096-.023.196.037.22.135.02.1-.04.196-.14.22m-.206 2.19c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.194.13-.22.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.05.2-.14.22m-.52-1.48c-.02-.094.04-.192.13-.215.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.097-.04.196-.14.22-.1.022-.2-.04-.22-.138M2.4 11.94c-.1.023-.193-.04-.22-.137-.02-.1.04-.198.14-.22.1-.02.197.04.22.137.02.1-.04.2-.135.22m-.21 2.19c-.095.02-.193-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.197.04.22.14.024.1-.04.2-.136.22m-.53-1.49c-.03-.1.04-.19.13-.22.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13m-.31-1.35c-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.09-.025.19.04.22.133.02.1-.04.193-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.1-1.22c-.1.025-.19-.036-.22-.135-.02-.1.04-.196.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.096-.04.195-.14.22m-.21 2.185c-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.134.03.1-.04.2-.13.22m-.53-1.49c-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.027.2.034.22.132.03.1-.03.2-.13.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.21-.14m.34-2.4c.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.52-.84c.1-.03.2.04.22.13.03.1-.03.2-.13.22-.09.02-.19-.04-.21-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.31 1.35c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.03.1-.03.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.21-2.19c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.32 3.68c.03.1-.03.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.02.19.04.21.14m-.01-2.33c.09-.03.19.03.22.13.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m.2-2.19c.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.14-.22m.31 1.35c.1-.03.2.04.22.13.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.2-2.2c.1-.03.2.03.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m.52 1.49c.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.026-.1.04-.2.133-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.13m0-2.32c.1-.02.2.04.22.132.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.09.03-.19-.03-.21-.13-.03-.1.04-.19.13-.22M4 5.642c.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.09.02-.19-.04-.21-.13-.03-.1.03-.19.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14M4 3.33c.096-.02.194.04.217.14.022.1-.04.2-.136.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.133-.02-.1.04-.196.14-.22m.53 1.494c.03.1-.03.2-.13.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14M4.53 2.5c.1-.024.2.04.22.136.03.098-.04.196-.13.22-.09.022-.19-.04-.22-.138-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22M4.2 7.23c-.1.025-.2-.036-.22-.135-.023-.098.04-.196.136-.218.1-.024.198.038.22.136.022.098-.04.196-.137.22m-.19 5.377c.09-.022.19.038.21.137.02.098-.04.196-.14.22-.09.022-.19-.04-.21-.138-.03-.1.03-.2.13-.22m-.31-1.36c.1-.03.2.03.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.21-2.19c.09-.03.19.04.22.13.02.09-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22m-.23-1c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.02.19.04.21.14.02.09-.04.19-.14.21m-.29 1.84c.09-.03.19.03.21.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m-.45-1.14c-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.03.2.04.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.3.97c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.14.22m.23 1c.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.09-.04.19-.14.21-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m1.57-.18c.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.03.19.04.22.13m.09 1.22c.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22M5 13.19c.023.1-.04.2-.137.22-.1.02-.198-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.13m.614.386c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22M12.38.01c5.825 3.736 7.257 11.643 3.944 19.74l-.93.213C19.1 11.43 17.304 3.35 11 .1c-.458.053-.926.13-1.403.226l4.598 19.915-.753.17L8.846.5c-.472.118-.928.256-1.363.408-.805 1.082-1.386 2.25-1.754 3.474.07.005.14.048.16.127.02.09-.04.19-.14.21-.04.01-.08-.01-.11-.02-.35 1.3-.46 2.66-.33 4.05.07.01.13.05.15.13.02.09-.04.18-.13.21.04.34.1.69.17 1.04.02-.01.03-.03.05-.04.09-.03.19.04.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.03 0-.05-.01-.08-.02.08.34.17.68.28 1.03.01-.01.01-.02.02-.02.09-.02.19.04.21.13.02.1-.04.2-.14.22h-.01c.11.35.25.7.39 1.05.02.02.05.05.06.09 0 .01-.01.03-.01.05.24.58.53 1.17.85 1.74.02-.03.05-.05.08-.06.1-.03.2.03.22.13.02.09-.04.18-.13.21.31.52.65 1.04 1.02 1.55.01 0 .02-.02.03-.02.1-.02.2.04.22.13.02.06-.01.12-.06.16.54.72 1.15 1.42 1.81 2.11.01-.01.01-.02.02-.02.1-.02.19.04.22.14.01.04-.01.07-.02.11.16.16.33.33.5.49-.03-.1.03-.19.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.03.01-.06-.01-.09-.02.3.28.61.57.93.85l-.93.21c-.12-.1-.22-.2-.33-.31-.03.05-.06.08-.12.09-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13-.01-.08.03-.15.09-.19-.95-.9-1.81-1.84-2.55-2.81.02.1-.04.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.04-.01.09 0 .12.02-.4-.53-.76-1.07-1.09-1.61-.03.03-.06.06-.1.07-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22h.01c-.57-.95-1.04-1.91-1.4-2.88-.1.01-.19-.04-.21-.14-.02-.08.02-.15.09-.19-.13-.36-.24-.72-.34-1.08-.03-.027-.06-.055-.07-.09-.01-.04 0-.07.02-.107-.1-.38-.19-.76-.26-1.14-.04-.02-.07-.06-.08-.11-.01-.053.01-.11.05-.15-.06-.355-.11-.71-.13-1.07l-.01.01c-.1.022-.2-.04-.22-.138-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.03-.01.05 0 .08.01-.03-.64-.02-1.28.05-1.908-.03-.02-.05-.04-.06-.08-.02-.078.02-.14.08-.18.08-.655.23-1.297.42-1.93-.02.02-.04.05-.08.055-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.025-.1.035-.195.134-.22.09-.02.174.04.203.12.07-.22.15-.434.233-.65-.02-.02-.05-.05-.06-.08-.02-.1.04-.196.14-.22.02-.003.03.007.04.007.23-.55.49-1.08.8-1.6C4.81 2 3.69 2.79 2.8 3.694c.006.01.02.02.02.03.02.1-.04.2-.135.22-.04.01-.083 0-.12-.02-.15.17-.3.34-.435.51.08 0 .15.05.17.13.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.09.02-.17-.03-.21-.12-.15.2-.29.41-.42.62.01 0 .013-.02.025-.02.1-.02.2.04.22.14.023.1-.04.2-.137.22-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.14v-.03c-.13.22-.248.436-.35.658.08 0 .16.04.18.13.02.095-.04.193-.14.22-.07.01-.128-.02-.17-.067-.09.21-.17.43-.24.64.003.01.02.02.02.03.02.08-.03.16-.104.2C.46 7.89.35 8.51.33 9.14c.09-.01.18.04.2.13.02.093-.04.19-.14.214-.02.005-.04-.008-.065-.01.004 1.23.305 2.487.923 3.72.098-.02.195.04.218.14.02.064-.01.12-.06.163.29.532.65 1.06 1.06 1.58.07.015.13.054.14.127.01.01 0 .03 0 .04.158.187.32.37.49.553-.022-.094.04-.192.136-.214.1-.02.2.04.22.133.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.04.01-.076-.004-.108-.02 1.166 1.226 2.7 2.37 4.63 3.374 1.233.64 2.555 1.567 2.79 2.594L11 23.36l6.677-1.54-.33-1.436c-.235-1.027.546-2.44 1.376-3.556 6.74-9.073 2.195-17-6.345-16.83"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only issue seems to be that both elements have same id, other than that it seems like a valid code to me

```
 <label for="id_icon-balloon1">
     <svg class="icon" id="icon-balloon">
         <use xlink:href="#icon-balloon"></use>
     </svg>
 </label>

<svg width="0" height="0" class="hide">
    <symbol id="_icon-balloon" viewBox="0 0 22 29">
        <title>Balloon</title>
        <path d="M11.65 25.56c.618 2.323.54 3.146 2.706 2.646l2.435-.563c2.17-.5 1.74-1.203 1.28-3.562l-6.41 1.48zm1.096-6.03c-.097.02-.195-.04-.217-.137-.03-.098.03-.196.13-.218.1-.024.19.038.22.136.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.53-1.49c-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.19.04.21.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.13m.01 2.33c-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13-.03-.1.03-.19.13-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.53-1.49c-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.03-.19-.04-.22-.13m-.31-1.35c-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.1-1.22c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.19.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.21 2.19c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.09-.02.19.04.21.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.53-1.5c-.03-.09.03-.19.13-.22.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.1-1.22c-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22M10.21 18c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.025-.1.04-.194.135-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.095-.04.194-.14.215m-.53-1.5c-.02-.097.04-.194.14-.217.1-.03.19.04.22.13.02.1-.04.196-.14.22-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14m-.3-1.353c-.02-.1.04-.197.138-.22.098-.025.197.036.22.134.02.1-.04.2-.136.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m.01 2.33c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.03.197.04.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22m-.53-1.49c-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.097-.03.195.03.217.13.02.1-.04.19-.138.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.31-1.36c-.027-.1.034-.2.132-.22.1-.03.197.04.22.13.023.1-.04.19-.14.22-.095.02-.193-.04-.215-.14m-.09-1.22c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.027-.1.035-.2.132-.22.1-.03.196.04.22.13.024.1-.04.2-.137.22m-.21 2.19c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.092-.02.192.04.213.14.03.09-.03.19-.13.22m-.52-1.49c-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.03.2.04.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.14M7.4 12.7c-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.03.093-.04.19-.13.22-.093.02-.193-.04-.22-.14m-.09-1.22c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.197.14-.22.1-.03.2.033.22.13.02.1-.04.197-.133.22m-.21 2.19c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.096.033-.194.13-.217.1-.023.2.04.22.137.025.1-.04.2-.135.22m-.52-1.48c-.026-.1.04-.19.135-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.026.1-.04.2-.135.22-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14m-.31-1.36c-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.1-.022.2.04.22.137.025.1-.04.193-.134.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14M5.95 9.5c-.02-.1.04-.196.14-.22.1-.02.196.04.22.14.03.09-.03.19-.13.21-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14m-.09-1.21c-.098.02-.196-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.137-.22.1-.02.196.04.22.14.02.093-.04.19-.136.22m-.32-1.37c-.09.022-.19-.038-.21-.137-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.096-.04.194-.14.22M6 5.733c.1-.026.2.035.22.133.03.1-.04.195-.13.22-.09.02-.19-.04-.21-.14-.02-.1.04-.195.14-.22m.21-2.19c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.196-.14.22-.09.02-.19-.04-.21-.14-.02-.096.04-.194.137-.22m.53 1.495c.027.1-.04.2-.133.22-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14-.022-.09.04-.19.137-.21.1-.02.2.04.22.14m-.02-2.32c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.03.1-.04.2-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22m.53 1.49c.03.1-.03.2-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.13-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14m-.02-2.35c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.03-.19-.04-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m.32 1.35c.1-.03.2.03.22.13.02.09-.04.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m.21-2.19c.1-.03.2.04.22.13.03.1-.04.2-.13.22-.09.03-.19-.04-.21-.13-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22m.53 1.5c.02.1-.04.2-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.1-.02.2.04.22.14m.31 1.36c.03.1-.03.2-.13.22-.09.03-.19-.04-.21-.13-.03-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14m-.01-2.33c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.03.1-.04.19-.13.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22M9 2.95c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.09-.033.19-.13.21-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22m.52 1.5c.03.1-.04.2-.13.22-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.022.19.04.21.138m.31 1.36c.02.094-.04.19-.14.214-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14-.02-.096.04-.195.14-.217.1-.02.19.04.22.14m.31 1.354c.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.21-.14-.024-.1.04-.19.136-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14m.31 1.36c.028.1-.033.2-.13.22-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.13-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.03.2.04.22.13m.31 1.35c.03.1-.036.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.094-.03.19.04.214.13m.32 1.35c.02.1-.04.192-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.092-.02.19.04.22.133m-.127 3.41c.1-.02.195.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.13-.022-.1.04-.198.138-.22m-.31-1.35c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m-.45-1.14c-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.21-.14m-.07 1.97c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.092-.04.19-.133.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.025-.1.04-.2.14-.22m-.33-1.37c.1-.02.195.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.137.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.138-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22m-.45-1.14c-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.03.1-.03.2-.13.22-.1.03-.19-.04-.22-.13m-.07 1.97c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.03.1-.04.2-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22M9 12.24c.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.193-.14.22-.093.02-.19-.04-.213-.14-.03-.1.03-.2.13-.22m-.32-1.35c.1-.027.195.04.22.133.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.193-.04-.22-.133-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22M8.2 9.75c-.02-.1.04-.194.14-.22.1-.02.197.04.22.14.02.095-.04.193-.14.22-.1.02-.193-.04-.22-.14m-.07 1.97c.1-.03.195.04.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.138.22-.1.02-.196-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.137-.22m-.32-1.37c.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.192-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.197.13-.22m-.36-1.38c.09-.022.19.04.22.138.02.098-.04.196-.14.22-.1.022-.2-.04-.22-.138-.02-.1.04-.197.14-.22m-.02-3.19c-.1.023-.2-.038-.22-.136-.03-.1.03-.197.13-.22.1-.023.19.04.22.137.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.44 1.14c.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.19.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14m.07-1.97c-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.25 3.32c.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.09.04-.19.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14m.07-1.97c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.45 1.14c.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.03-.19.13-.22.09-.02.19.04.21.14m.07-1.97c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.32 1.35c-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13-.03-.1.04-.19.14-.22.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.21 2.19c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.09.04-.19.13-.21.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.23 1c.09-.02.19.04.21.14.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.29-1.83c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.193.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.54 2.35c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.023.1-.04.2-.138.22-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.19.135-.22m-.23-1c-.097.03-.19-.04-.217-.13-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.09-.02.19.04.21.14.03.1-.04.2-.13.22M7 7.83c-.022-.1.04-.2.137-.22.098-.026.196.04.218.134.024.1-.038.19-.135.22-.1.02-.197-.04-.22-.14m-.07 1.97c.095-.02.194.04.218.13.022.1-.04.19-.138.22-.098.02-.197-.04-.217-.14-.026-.1.036-.2.136-.22m-.25-3.32c-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.31.97c-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.13-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m.23 1c.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.197-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.193.13-.22m4.7 4.098c.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.03.19.03.22.13m.31 1.36c.02.09-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.03.2.03.22.13m.31 1.36c.02.09-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.028.19.033.21.13m.32 1.36c.03.1-.04.2-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.19.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.21.14M10 20.17c-.1.02-.194-.04-.22-.137-.02-.1.04-.193.14-.22.1-.02.198.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.135.22m-.84-.52c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.135-.02-.1.04-.197.14-.22.1-.02.195.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.834-.52c-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.14-.02-.097.04-.195.14-.218.1-.03.2.032.22.13.02.1-.04.196-.14.22m-.83-.53c-.1.022-.19-.04-.22-.136-.02-.1.04-.196.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.196-.14.22M7 17.1c-.023-.096.037-.195.136-.217.1-.023.196.038.22.135.022.1-.04.198-.138.22-.098.022-.197-.038-.22-.137m-.3.98c-.1.02-.197-.04-.22-.13-.022-.1.04-.19.136-.22.098-.02.196.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.137.22m-.533-1.49c-.02-.09.04-.19.138-.21.098-.02.195.04.218.14.023.1-.038.2-.136.22-.1.02-.197-.04-.22-.14m-.312-1.35c-.023-.1.04-.19.137-.22.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.13m.01 2.32c-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22m-.53-1.49c-.03-.09.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.19.04.21.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.13M5 14.73c-.02-.1.04-.2.136-.22.1-.02.197.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.138.22-.1.02-.197-.04-.22-.14m.01 2.322c-.098.02-.196-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.137-.22.1-.02.197.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.136.21m-.53-1.5c-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.024.19.04.21.136.03.09-.04.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.31-1.35c-.03-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.13.02.1-.03.2-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m.01 2.32c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.02.19.04.21.13.02.1-.04.2-.14.22M3.64 15c-.02-.093.04-.19.14-.213.1-.025.19.037.22.135.02.1-.04.195-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.31-1.355c-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.198-.14.22-.1.025-.2-.04-.22-.134m-.097-1.22c-.093.024-.19-.04-.213-.136-.025-.095.036-.193.135-.215.096-.023.196.037.22.135.02.1-.04.196-.14.22m-.206 2.19c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.194.13-.22.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.05.2-.14.22m-.52-1.48c-.02-.094.04-.192.13-.215.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.097-.04.196-.14.22-.1.022-.2-.04-.22-.138M2.4 11.94c-.1.023-.193-.04-.22-.137-.02-.1.04-.198.14-.22.1-.02.197.04.22.137.02.1-.04.2-.135.22m-.21 2.19c-.095.02-.193-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.197.04.22.14.024.1-.04.2-.136.22m-.53-1.49c-.03-.1.04-.19.13-.22.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13m-.31-1.35c-.02-.09.04-.19.14-.21.09-.025.19.04.22.133.02.1-.04.193-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.1-1.22c-.1.025-.19-.036-.22-.135-.02-.1.04-.196.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.096-.04.195-.14.22m-.21 2.185c-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.134.03.1-.04.2-.13.22m-.53-1.49c-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.027.2.034.22.132.03.1-.03.2-.13.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.21-.14m.34-2.4c.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.52-.84c.1-.03.2.04.22.13.03.1-.03.2-.13.22-.09.02-.19-.04-.21-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.31 1.35c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.03.1-.03.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.21-2.19c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.32 3.68c.03.1-.03.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.02.19.04.21.14m-.01-2.33c.09-.03.19.03.22.13.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m.2-2.19c.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.14-.22m.31 1.35c.1-.03.2.04.22.13.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.2-2.2c.1-.03.2.03.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m.52 1.49c.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.026-.1.04-.2.133-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.13m0-2.32c.1-.02.2.04.22.132.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.09.03-.19-.03-.21-.13-.03-.1.04-.19.13-.22M4 5.642c.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.09.02-.19-.04-.21-.13-.03-.1.03-.19.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14M4 3.33c.096-.02.194.04.217.14.022.1-.04.2-.136.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.133-.02-.1.04-.196.14-.22m.53 1.494c.03.1-.03.2-.13.22-.1.02-.19-.04-.22-.13-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14M4.53 2.5c.1-.024.2.04.22.136.03.098-.04.196-.13.22-.09.022-.19-.04-.22-.138-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22M4.2 7.23c-.1.025-.2-.036-.22-.135-.023-.098.04-.196.136-.218.1-.024.198.038.22.136.022.098-.04.196-.137.22m-.19 5.377c.09-.022.19.038.21.137.02.098-.04.196-.14.22-.09.022-.19-.04-.21-.138-.03-.1.03-.2.13-.22m-.31-1.36c.1-.03.2.03.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22m.21-2.19c.09-.03.19.04.22.13.02.09-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.13-.22m-.23-1c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.03-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.02.19.04.21.14.02.09-.04.19-.14.21m-.29 1.84c.09-.03.19.03.21.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m-.45-1.14c-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.03.2.04.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14m-.3.97c-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.13-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.14.22m.23 1c.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.09-.04.19-.14.21-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22m1.57-.18c.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.09-.03.19.04.22.13m.09 1.22c.09-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22M5 13.19c.023.1-.04.2-.137.22-.1.02-.198-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.1-.02.2.04.22.13m.614.386c.1-.02.2.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.19.14-.22M12.38.01c5.825 3.736 7.257 11.643 3.944 19.74l-.93.213C19.1 11.43 17.304 3.35 11 .1c-.458.053-.926.13-1.403.226l4.598 19.915-.753.17L8.846.5c-.472.118-.928.256-1.363.408-.805 1.082-1.386 2.25-1.754 3.474.07.005.14.048.16.127.02.09-.04.19-.14.21-.04.01-.08-.01-.11-.02-.35 1.3-.46 2.66-.33 4.05.07.01.13.05.15.13.02.09-.04.18-.13.21.04.34.1.69.17 1.04.02-.01.03-.03.05-.04.09-.03.19.04.22.13.02.1-.04.19-.14.22-.03 0-.05-.01-.08-.02.08.34.17.68.28 1.03.01-.01.01-.02.02-.02.09-.02.19.04.21.13.02.1-.04.2-.14.22h-.01c.11.35.25.7.39 1.05.02.02.05.05.06.09 0 .01-.01.03-.01.05.24.58.53 1.17.85 1.74.02-.03.05-.05.08-.06.1-.03.2.03.22.13.02.09-.04.18-.13.21.31.52.65 1.04 1.02 1.55.01 0 .02-.02.03-.02.1-.02.2.04.22.13.02.06-.01.12-.06.16.54.72 1.15 1.42 1.81 2.11.01-.01.01-.02.02-.02.1-.02.19.04.22.14.01.04-.01.07-.02.11.16.16.33.33.5.49-.03-.1.03-.19.13-.22.1-.02.19.04.22.14.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.03.01-.06-.01-.09-.02.3.28.61.57.93.85l-.93.21c-.12-.1-.22-.2-.33-.31-.03.05-.06.08-.12.09-.1.03-.2-.03-.22-.13-.01-.08.03-.15.09-.19-.95-.9-1.81-1.84-2.55-2.81.02.1-.04.19-.13.22-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.04-.01.09 0 .12.02-.4-.53-.76-1.07-1.09-1.61-.03.03-.06.06-.1.07-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22h.01c-.57-.95-1.04-1.91-1.4-2.88-.1.01-.19-.04-.21-.14-.02-.08.02-.15.09-.19-.13-.36-.24-.72-.34-1.08-.03-.027-.06-.055-.07-.09-.01-.04 0-.07.02-.107-.1-.38-.19-.76-.26-1.14-.04-.02-.07-.06-.08-.11-.01-.053.01-.11.05-.15-.06-.355-.11-.71-.13-1.07l-.01.01c-.1.022-.2-.04-.22-.138-.02-.1.04-.2.14-.22.03-.01.05 0 .08.01-.03-.64-.02-1.28.05-1.908-.03-.02-.05-.04-.06-.08-.02-.078.02-.14.08-.18.08-.655.23-1.297.42-1.93-.02.02-.04.05-.08.055-.1.02-.2-.04-.22-.14-.025-.1.035-.195.134-.22.09-.02.174.04.203.12.07-.22.15-.434.233-.65-.02-.02-.05-.05-.06-.08-.02-.1.04-.196.14-.22.02-.003.03.007.04.007.23-.55.49-1.08.8-1.6C4.81 2 3.69 2.79 2.8 3.694c.006.01.02.02.02.03.02.1-.04.2-.135.22-.04.01-.083 0-.12-.02-.15.17-.3.34-.435.51.08 0 .15.05.17.13.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.09.02-.17-.03-.21-.12-.15.2-.29.41-.42.62.01 0 .013-.02.025-.02.1-.02.2.04.22.14.023.1-.04.2-.137.22-.1.03-.2-.04-.22-.14v-.03c-.13.22-.248.436-.35.658.08 0 .16.04.18.13.02.095-.04.193-.14.22-.07.01-.128-.02-.17-.067-.09.21-.17.43-.24.64.003.01.02.02.02.03.02.08-.03.16-.104.2C.46 7.89.35 8.51.33 9.14c.09-.01.18.04.2.13.02.093-.04.19-.14.214-.02.005-.04-.008-.065-.01.004 1.23.305 2.487.923 3.72.098-.02.195.04.218.14.02.064-.01.12-.06.163.29.532.65 1.06 1.06 1.58.07.015.13.054.14.127.01.01 0 .03 0 .04.158.187.32.37.49.553-.022-.094.04-.192.136-.214.1-.02.2.04.22.133.02.1-.04.2-.14.22-.04.01-.076-.004-.108-.02 1.166 1.226 2.7 2.37 4.63 3.374 1.233.64 2.555 1.567 2.79 2.594L11 23.36l6.677-1.54-.33-1.436c-.235-1.027.546-2.44 1.376-3.556 6.74-9.073 2.195-17-6.345-16.83"/>
    </symbol>
    (...) //other icons
</svg>
```

maybe add to your svg tags:

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
```

as they help to ensure it works in all browsers etc.